# Is there any usecase for a coroutine with only a co_return; at the end?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm curious because I read the following in Josuttis' book:

> In case none of these keywords [`co_await`/`co_yield`/`co_return`] is necessary inside a coroutine, you have to explicitly write a `co_return;` statement at the end.

The quote makes me understand that in principle the answer is positive, i.e. it could be useful.

But do you have examples of it?

---

From what I read [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#5), my first impression is that if the only `co_*` expression in the coroutine is the `co_return;` as its last statement, all that could happen when calling such a coroutine with respect to when calling a normal `void` function with a `return` at the end would be

- some code running before it via `co_await promise.initial_suspend();`,
- exception handling via `try`/`catch`/`promise.unhandled_exception();`,
- some more code running after it via `co_await promise.final_suspend();`.

But nothing of that happens *during* the body of the coroutine. In other words the coroutine is entered only once, at the beginning, and exited only once, at the end, just like a normal function; no suspension-followed-by-resumption that is the workflow coroutines are made to provide, no?. Whatever those 3 bullet points above do, I could write it in place before the call, around the call, and after the call respectively.

So, to reiterate the question, is there any practical reason why I would want a coroutine with just a `co_return;` at the end?

Comment: A possibility is that a code expects you to pass it a coroutine (not a void function) and all you need is a stub.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a virtual base class that defines a virtual coroutine that is dispatched at runtime:

```cpp
struct Base {
    virtual promise<void> coro() = 0;
};
```

And then you have multiple subclasses that implement that coroutine. Some subclasses actually use the full features of the coroutine itself, while others may not need that and just execute some code and then `co_return` at the end.

Basically, when you have any kind of dynamic dispatch to various coroutines, and some of the coroutines dispatched to are "trivial", then this would come up. This doesn't have to be virtual functions, that was just one example.

You're right that it probably doesn't make much sense to write such a coroutine in a standalone manner, if it's only ever called directly, you'd be better off with a standard function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not saying there are cases where a `co_return;` is necessary, it's saying if there isn't any of those three, you aren't in a coroutine. You can have an ordinary function that returns an awaitable that it got from somewhere.

It might be that the book is thinking of particular awaitables that aren't default-constructible, or do something in their promise's return_void that isn't otherwise accessible.